# Multiple test mock runtimes with slightly different configs based off common base?

Tags: rust, mock, types, traits

We have some custom pallet unit tests that use multiple mock runtimes that are configured slightly differently.  The problem is that when we have to make changes to the runtime, we have to apply those changes to all of them. Furthermore, we'd like to have a set of common functions that all of the unit tests can use.  If Rust had inheritance, the solution would be an abstract base runtime and subclasses for each runtime but Rust doesn't have it.  The solution likely involves creative use of modules and macros but what's the recommended approach?

I'd like to avoid making changes to the `Cargo.toml`.  I'd like to have some sort of macro level attribute that I could set in each runtime:  `"runtime1"` and `"runtime2"` and then conditionally compile which value is used based on that attribute.

In our case, we have two runtimes that differ only by the constant values for two of the associated types.

*e.g.*

```
type MaxMessagesStored = ConstU32<25>;  // runtime1
```

and

```
type MaxMessagesStored = ConstU32<1000>;  // runtime2
```

So, I'd like something like this.  This code is for example and does **NOT** work:

```
#![cfg_attr(RUNTIME, define = "runtime1")]

    #[cfg(RUNTIME = "runtime1")]
    type MaxMessagesStored = ConstU32<25>;
    #[cfg(RUNTIME = "runtime2")]
    type MaxMessagesStored = ConstU32<1000>;
```

In C, this would be:

```
    #define RUNTIME "runtime1"
    
    #if defined(RUNTIME) && (RUNTIME == "runtime1")
    // code 
    #else
    // code
    #endif
```

Alternatively, is there a way to change the value at runtime?  I assume not because it's a constant but have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is using macro.

Sometimes, we need to speed up the session time for the development runtimes.

So, we have a `fast-runtime` macro.

Check how `fast-runtime` works: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/a8e6828115f852dc08a90c9fc0698f59a589b977/runtime/common/src/lib.rs#L247-L275

You can simply replace the `fast-runtime` with something like `multi-runtimes` and make accepting more args.